# jquery help: how to get message after selecting radio button and select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, alert

if i have selected one radio button and then if i select a value from select box I should get a message.

HTML:

```
First Class<input name="seat_class" id="a1" type="radio" value="First Class">
Second Class <input name="seat_class" id="a2" type="radio" value="Standard Class" />

 <select id="op" name="myname">
 <option value="none" selected>None</option>
<option value="rahul" selected>Rahul</option>
<option value="aisha">aisha</option>
</select>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){


$('#a1').change(function() {

  $('#op').change(function(){
      if($(this).val()==rahul)
      {
alert("Hello yar " + $(this).val());
      }
});

  //alert('foo');

});

$('#a2').change(function() {
  alert('bar');

});

$('#op').change(function(){
alert("Hello " + $(this).val());
});

})
```

This code is not working any how.

I want that when i select radio button 1 and rahul i should get a message, and if i select radio button 2 and aisha i should get another message.
Please help.

Comment: Any chance you could express "not working" with a bit more precision?

Comment: You have alot of nested selectors there, you cant bind to an event inside of another selector. Ill get a jsfiddle up for you.

Comment: btw, it is not nassecary to wrap a document.ready around the event handlers. And I think your main mistake is the missing quotation. Correct must be: == 'rahul'

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/jX5uT/

Hope that helps.

You cant bind to events inside of other event bindings. You can however use a selector to do other things inside of a binding.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you the basics:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[type=radio]").click(function(){
        if($("#a1").is(":checked")) { 
            $('#op').change(function(){       
                if($(this).val()== "rahul"){ 
                    alert("Hello yar " + $(this).val());       
                } 
            }); 
        }   
    });
});
```

Don't forget "rahul" needs to be in quotes otherwise it will think it is a variable.

Good luck!